# Receiving Data Through Audio Jack

Tags: iphone, audio

Does anyone know of any **recent** examples of receiving data through the iPhone's audio jack? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not an example but a method:

I would think the data is exchanged with different audio tones, perhaps FSK or another tone encoding scheme such as DTMF.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your correct but I cannot figure out how to access the audio jack.

Comment: The same way you obtain sound from the microphone through the audio jack. Look for Apple audio examples.