# How to send/receive data through audio jack in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

We are looking for the ways to handle data transfer using audio jack in iOS. 
We searched a lot to see whether it is possible to have this two way data communication through iPhone's audio jack, but had no luck yet. As per mentioned in some forums its possible, but again ended up with kind of vague answers which are more of theoretical-
[Receiving Data Through Audio Jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575982/receiving-data-through-audio-jack)
[Force iPhone to read in data through headphone jack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343496/force-iphone-to-read-in-data-through-headphone-jack)
http://hackaday.com/2010/02/01/android-audio-serial-connection/

So far we understand the app needs to be able to perform below things:

1. Check whether audio jack is ready to transfer the data with cable is already inserted into it
2. Sending Data : Data on your iPhone should be converted into analogue signals as you are going to transfer it using audio connector.
3. Receiving Data : Data will be received as analogue signals which should be converted to digital to read it back.

Please correct me or add up if anything is missing. Also wanted to ensure whether direct communication is possible. Ex. If I want to transfer data from my iPhone to Mac machine. Do we need to have dependency over any middleware hardware which then handles the signal conversion.

It would be really great if anyone is aware of any available 'libraries / APIs / well-defined process' which can be good enough to make a start..

Any help in this regard will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Comment: Doing data transfer using audio jack will create a lot of data lose due to the audio processing units. One way that comes to my mind is to try implementing using the idea of spread spectrum for minimizing the error. As to how to send and receive signal [Portaudio](http://www.portaudio.com/) might help to create the app on mac side.

Comment: These might be useful: http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~prabal/projects/hijack/   
and http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/hijack-development-pack-p-865.html